# "Shaking Effect" only lasts through one cylce

Tags: javascript, rotation

I'm trying to make an element that shakes back and forth and gets smaller and resets afterward to its original size on click. The issue is when clicking, it seems to go through the size cycle but after the first one, it will no longer shake. If tried moving funcitons here and there, but nothing seems to work. Is there any mistake in my code that is causing this?

```js
var rotated = false;
var height = 24.6;
var width = 15

var points = 0;

function cl() {
  width = width / 1.1;
  height = height / 1.1;
}

function clicked() {
  document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box'),
      deg = rotated ? 0 : 30;

    div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    setInterval(res, 140);
  }
}

function res() {
  var div = document.getElementById('box'),
    deg = rotated ? 0 : 0;
  div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}





setInterval(gamerule, 10);

function gamerule() {
  var div = document.getElementById('box');
  div.style.width = width + "%";
  div.style.height = height + "%";

  if (width < 1) {
    width = 15;
    height = 24.6;
    document.getElementById("cont").style.pointerEvents = "none";
    setInterval(ser, 1000);
    points++;

    function ser() {
      document.getElementById("cont").style.pointerEvents = "all";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#cont {
  width: 90%;
  height: 104%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 65px;
  top: -30px;
}

#box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 24.6%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35.7%;
  left: 41.7%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont" onclick="cl()">
  <div id="box" onclick="clicked()">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you had a bunch of junk code so I removed that. Also you had a setInterval instead of a setTimeout.

```js
var rotated = false;
var height = 24.6;
var width = 15

var points = 0;
document.querySelector("#box").addEventListener("click", clickFunction);
// Call this function to simulate the click
function clickFunction() {
  width = width / 1.1;
  height = height / 1.1;
  var div = document.getElementById("box"),
      deg = rotated ? 0 : 30;

  div.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  div.style.mozTransform    = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  div.style.msTransform     = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  div.style.oTransform      = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  div.style.transform       = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  // You had set Interval I changed it to setTimeout
  setTimeout(res, 140);
}

 function res() {
  var div = document.getElementById("box"),
      deg = rotated ? 0 : 0;
  div.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  div.style.mozTransform    = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  div.style.msTransform     = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  div.style.oTransform      = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
  div.style.transform       = "rotate("+deg+"deg)";
}





setInterval(gamerule, 10);
function gamerule() {
  var div = document.getElementById("box");
  div.style.width           = width + "%";
  div.style.height          = height + "%";

  if (width < 1) {
    width = 15;
    height = 24.6;
    document.getElementById("cont").style.pointerEvents = "none";
    setInterval(ser, 1000);
    points++;
    function ser() {
        document.getElementById("cont").style.pointerEvents = "all";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
#cont{
  width:90%;
  height:104%;
  background-color:white;
  position:absolute;
  left:65px;
  top:-30px;
}
#box{
  background-color:black;
  width:15%;
  height:24.6%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position:absolute;
  top:35.7%;
  left:41.7%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cont">
      <div id="box">

      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works but, how do I call on that whole script from another function, like if I wanted to automatically "click" the box every second.

Comment: @Benn   I changed the script to allow you to call it independently, just call "clickFunction()" to simulate the click

Comment: It seems to ignore the cooldown, anyway you could make it listen to that. It also does not teeter left in right and instead stays in a right position

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the assignment of `deg` within `cl`, because at the moment it's always set to 0:

```
deg = rotated ? 0 : 30; // Or whatever value you want...
```

Then you need to inverse the value of `rotated`

```
rotated = !rotated;
```

Hopefully I've understand your problem correctly...

```js
var rotated = false;
var height = 24.6;
var width = 15

var points = 0;
var interval;

function cl() {
  width = width / 1.1;
  height = height / 1.1;
}

function clicked() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box'),
      deg = rotated ? 0 : 30;

    div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    if (interval == null) {
      interval = setInterval(res, 140);
    }
}

function res() {
  var div = document.getElementById('box'),
    deg = rotated ? 0 : 45;
  rotated = !rotated;
  div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}





setInterval(gamerule, 10);

function gamerule() {
  var div = document.getElementById('box');
  div.style.width = width + "%";
  div.style.height = height + "%";

  if (width < 1) {
    width = 15;
    height = 24.6;
    document.getElementById("cont").style.pointerEvents = "none";
    setInterval(ser, 1000);
    points++;

    function ser() {
      document.getElementById("cont").style.pointerEvents = "all";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#cont {
  width: 90%;
  height: 104%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 65px;
  top: -30px;
}

#box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 24.6%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35.7%;
  left: 41.7%;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont" onclick="cl()">
  <div id="box" onclick="clicked()">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works but, how do I call on that whole script from another function, like if I wanted to automatically "click" the box every second.